# how to log in instagram of the mobile version with ruby

Tags: ios, ruby, selenium, mobile, authentication

I use the selenium in ruby and  successfully log into instagram of the PC version.but I want to log in the instagram of the ios app instagram. What to do?

Comment: You mean the Instagram iios app or the Instagram website on a mobile viewport?

Comment: sorry,I mean that logging in instagram ios app.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not possible but you can take a look to http://appium.io.